# Correct Way to Read GraphML files with Gremlin using Groovy

Tags: groovy, gremlin

I am trying to read a GraphML file and use it with a Gremlin traversal. I'm using the same code as on this page:

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/

I write the example graph with writeGraph and read it back in with readGraph. The toString() call on the graph makes it 
appear that the graph was read in correctly (each has 6 nodes and 6 vertices), but then the applying the Gremlin traversal only
produces output for the TinkerFactory graph and not the one that was read in.

## Code

```
@Grab('org.apache.tinkerpop:tinkergraph-gremlin:3.1.1-incubating')
@Grab('org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-core:3.1.1-incubating')

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.IoCore;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph;

final Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).writeGraph("test.xml");
final Graph newGraph = TinkerGraph.open();
newGraph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph("test.xml");

def g = graph.traversal();
def n = newGraph.traversal();

println("Graph")
println(g.toString())
g.V(1).out().values('name').sideEffect{println it}.iterate()

println("newGraph")
println(n.toString())
n.V(1).out().values('name').sideEffect{println it}.iterate()

println("DONE")
```

## Output

```
Graph
graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
lop
vadas
josh
newGraph
graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
DONE
```

The code appears to be working with GraphSON and Gyro outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [related post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/eTtm49ZoT_g/kGrDQ3fXOk4J) from the Gremlin-Users mailing list. When you read in `newGraph`, the ids are being treated as `String`. You can change this behavior by configuring a `vertexIdManager` like this:

```
def conf = new org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager","LONG");
final Graph newGraph = TinkerGraph.open(conf);
newGraph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph(dest);
```